# Issues storing a NSArray in CoreData [Swift]

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift

I'm trying to save an Array: `var upKNOArray: [Int] = []` to a `Transformable` in CoreData.
It successfully saves using this code:

```swift
let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName( "SavedData", inManagedObjectContext: context )
var newItem = data( entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context )
var error : NSError?
newItem.upKNOs = upKNOArray
newItem.downKNOs = downKNOArray
if !context.save(&error) {
    NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
}
```

The problem is when the application is ran again and it tries to fetch the CoreData on load with this code:

```swift
func fetchCoreData(){
  var error : NSError?
  let appDel : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
  let context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"SavedData")
  let fetchedResults = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as [data]?
  if let resultsArray = fetchedResults {
    if resultsArray.count > 0 {
    let newItem = resultsArray[0] as data
    clientID = newItem.userid
    upKNOArray = newItem.upKNOs // THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH HAPPENS
    downKNOArray = newItem.downKNOs as [Int]
    NSLog("Saved data is \(newItem.userid)")
    }
  }
```

I have commented on the line that receives the error at runtime.
The error is: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is it the stored data making this problem occur or is it how I am fetching? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The crash log message tells you what's wrong. What does it _say_?

Comment: @matt it says `(lldb)` in the console and in the code it's highlighted in green and it says `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` That tells me nothing about what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I decided instead of storing the actual array in CoreData, I stored the `array.description` in a `String` and created a handle to convert the `String` back to an array.